# Can't set specific spacing when using UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to recreate pinterest UI, basically auto height for cell base on photo height.

[image]

I'm already able to make it height dynamic but the spacing for each cell is weird, it keeps auto set my cell spacing like this:

[image]

This is the code I used for collectionView:

```
  func setupCollectionView() {
        let layout2: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let width = view.frame.size.width * 0.9
        collectionViewParent = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout2)
        collectionViewParent.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(collectionViewParent)
        collectionViewParent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionViewParent.dataSource = self
        collectionViewParent.delegate = self
        collectionViewParent.register(LoansCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellLoan")
        collectionViewParent.register(FirstRowCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellFirst")

        collectionViewParent.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        collectionViewParent.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        collectionViewParent.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionViewParent.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        
        if let flowLayout = collectionViewParent.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
                flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
                flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
                flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical

        }
    }
```

For the cell, I just put everything in a UIView:

```
        addSubview(view) //view is a uiview
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8)/2)).isActive = true
        view.addSubview(labelEligible)
        
        labelEligible.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        labelEligible.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelEligible.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        addSubview(labelPrice)
        labelPrice.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        labelPrice.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        view.addSubview(labelDescription)
        labelDescription.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelPrice.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        labelDescription.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        labelDescription.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        
        view.addSubview(labelPayUpTo)
        labelPayUpTo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelDescription.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        labelPayUpTo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        labelPayUpTo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        let finalConstraint = labelPayUpTo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
        finalConstraint.isActive = true
        finalConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
```

Comment: First, what method are you calling `setupCollectionView` from? Second, rather than constraining centerX and width I would using leadingAnchor and trailingAnchor to constrain the horizontal. Third, as for your cells, it looks like width of your "asd" labels are determining the width of the cells. Lastly, what are the constraints for the imageView in your cells (vertical and horizontal)?

Comment: Also your final O/P is not same as the image you posted in question, so clearly your layout is not actually mimicking pinterest layout, you can either subclass a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`  or use compositional flow layout to achieve the desired effect

Comment: @Rob I updated the code for setup cell's UI. I call setupCollectionView from viewDidload

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I'm sorry but I don't understand what you've said, what do you mean the image is not the same?

Comment: @bao-le read https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: For collectionViewParent get rid of your heightAnchor and centerX widthAnchor. Use leadingAnchor and trailingAnchor instead. Also don't pin labelDescription.leadingAnchor and labelDescription.trailingAnchor to view. Pin them to imageView. Your labelDescription is determining the width of your cells.

Comment: @Rob Did what you said but the error is still remain