# How to set Size for a specific cell when using dynamic size uicollectionView cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

To achieve this layout
[image]

Basically a horizontal `collectionView` in `section 1` and a vertical `collectionView` in `section 2`

My thought was putting a collectionView inside the first cell, which should have the size: `CGSize(width: screen.width, height: 100)`

But since I'm using the method from the link, I don't know how to give a specific size for the first cell. This is what I've tried:

[image]

Comment: Are you required to use a `UICollectionView` to stack the horizontal collection on the vertical collection?  (are you trying to do that because the tutorial is about `UICollectionView`) I would probably be inclined to try a `UIStackView` as the container of the two `UICollectionViews`.

Comment: I haven't try that method yet but I need to scroll the entire view when the vertical one is scrolled and Im not sure using `StackView` can do that

Comment: Well... you could put the stack view inside of a `UIScrollView`, but I get the sense that the idea here is to solve the problem using nested `UICollectionViews`  so that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** As OP had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748502/cant-set-specific-spacing-when-using-uicollectionviewflowlayout-automaticsize) earlier on how to create a Pinterest layout and I had suggested Raywenderlich tutorial in comments, I believe this question from OP is extension of that

**Answer:**

Looking at the design you added, I believe you are trying to add a `CollectionView` with a horizontal scroll as the first cell which spans the entire collection view width. Because you have subclassed the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` you need to handle this special case in `prepare` method itself

```
    override func prepare() {
        // 1
        guard
            cache.isEmpty,
            let collectionView = collectionView
        else {
            return
        }
        // 2
        let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        var xOffset: [CGFloat] = []
        for column in 0..<numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
        }
        var column = 0
        var yOffset: [CGFloat] = .init(repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)

        // 3
        for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            let attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
            let photoHeight = delegate?.collectionView(
                collectionView,
                heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath) ?? 180
            let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
            let frame: CGRect

            if item == 0 {
                frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                               y: yOffset[column],
                               width: columnWidth,
                               height: height)

                contentHeight = frame.maxY
                for column in 0..<numberOfColumns {
                    yOffset[column] = frame.maxY
                }
                column = 0
            }
            else {
                // 4
                frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column],
                               y: yOffset[column],
                               width: columnWidth,
                               height: height)

                contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
                yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height
                column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
            }

            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)
            attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)
        }
    }
```

In your `for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {` I have added a special condition for handling `if item == 0 {` where in instead of using column width, I have used content width (as per your design you want first cell to cover the whole width of collection view)

Finally in your delegate method

```
extension PhotoStreamViewController: PinterestLayoutDelegate {
  func collectionView(
      _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
      heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
          if indexPath.row == 0 {
              return 180 // whatever is the height of first cell
          }
          return photos[indexPath.item].image.size.height
      }
}
```

**A word of caution**

In your design I can see that you have added two section headers **Header 1**  and **Header 2** I guess in that case your returning number of sections as at least 2, but the tutorial focuses on a single section collection view, if you notice

```
for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
```

section 0 is hard coded, you might have to handle it dynamically if you wanna handle multiple sections and might need a lot of reworking around `prepare`

Comment: just need to change `width: columnWidth` to `width: contentWidth` and everything works. Thank you!!!

Comment: @bao le: am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

A strategy you might follow to gain the ability to control the size of your collection items is to have your delegate for the `UICollection` view derive from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` instead of just from `UICollectionViewDelegate`.  By deriving from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` your delegate can implement:

```
func collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

And tell the system the size of the first item.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I have UILabel or UIImageView in the cell, it autogrows or shrinks depending on text or image size.